# How to print a variable with perror

Tags: c

I would like to print a variable with perror, i.e. I would like to write something like `perror("error with something %s", my_var)`

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: You might want to read about the [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `fprintf()` instead

```
fprintf(stderr, "error with something %s", my_var);
perror("");
```

Otherwise you can build a string, then pass it to perror

```
char yourstring[100];
snprintf(yourstring, sizeof yourstring, "error with something %s", my_var);
perror(yourstring);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it has already been answered, but I feel like there is a cleaner version of it

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error on line %d : %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
// Error on line 42 : Wrong argument
```